# CSS styles only for iOS web app?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, web-applications

Does anyone know if its possible to have CSS exclusive to an iOS web app?

ie. If the standalone web app is open call this style (vs. the style sheet of the mobile website web in Safari). I'd assume it be done with JS but can't find documentation.

Comment: Why do you need to only target iOS?  Is it for size reasons or because you need to detect touch events?

Comment: Not exclusive In only for iOS. but a specific style independent from the main css that is read when the page is opens up via standalone as a web app from the iOS home screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
 //Lines split for easy reading only  

    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)))
{
       //LINK TO YOUR STYLESHEET
 }
```

Comment: Thanks (ill try it out) where did you find that documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Html file with css file.just include the content file in web view

```
NSString *fileString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"privacypolicy" ofType:@"html"];
myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
NSString *newHTMLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fileString encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding error: NULL];
NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: fileString];
```

Its work fine

Comment: He isn't referring to web-view - its the standalone mode - when you bookmark a site from Safari to the Homescreen and then open it up (in fullscreen)